# Apply CSS styles only to the last row in the tree data

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to select last child/row in a tree data view via CSS. I could not find a selector that specify that the row is last child in tree view. Also the length of child rows is not fixed i.e there can be n child in a tree structure

For example

parent row

-- first child row

-- can be any no. of row in between

-- last child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass [`getRowStyle`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/#row-style) props callback to set the row styles conditionally. In this case you should check for rows that are `RowNode.lastChild`.

*EDIT*: If you don't want to apply the styles to the very last row of the grid, you may want to filter out `RowNode`s at level 0

```js
<AgGridReact
  treeData
  getRowStyle={(e) => {
    if (e.node.lastChild && e.node.level > 0) {
      return { backgroundColor: "pink" };
    }
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

If you use css module, you can specify a class for specific rows to be styled based on a condition using [`getRowClass`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/#row-class).

```js
<AgGridReact
  treeData
  getRowClass={(e) => {
    if (e.node.lastChild && e.node.level > 0) {
      return "last-child";
    }
    return "";
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

In your css file

```css
.last-child {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit AgGrid Tree Last Child]

Comment: Thanks @NearHuscarl. How to not apply color to last row in grid and only apply color to last row in tree view?

Comment: @precious If you don't want to apply the styles to the very last row of the grid, simply filter out `RowNode` with level 0. See my updated answer.

Comment: yeah got it. Thanks for your help. It was very useful 